# Trying to give column in sqlite database unique constraint

Tags: database, sqlite

I have an SQLite database, and I'm trying to give one of the columns a unique constraint. When I try, I get "Error: UNIQUE constraint failed."

I'm thinking it might be because I already have some duplicates in the table. I tried deleting the duplicates, but that gives me another error "FOREIGN KEY constraint failed," I think because my program calls those rows in various places. So now I'm stumped. (None of the data is important, I don't mind deleting it, just not sure how or if that would fix anything.)

I'm using SQLiteStudio to make these changes by the way, so any suggestions for fixing this using SQLiteStudio would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A FOREIGN KEY is a field (or collection of fields) in one table that refers to the PRIMARY KEY in another table.